# How to use Python to create a Google calendar event through API v3

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

The following official page gives an example on how to create an event with Python. 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples

The code they gave is listed below:

```
event = {
  'summary': 'Appointment',
  'location': 'Somewhere',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00'
  },
  'end': {
   'dateTime': '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00'
  },
  'attendees': [
  {
    'email': 'attendeeEmail',
    # Other attendee's data...
  },
  # ...
  ],
}

created_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()

print created_event['id']
```

However, the above example doesn't tell how to establish a connection and create the `service` variable. As I have set my calendar as public, I think it would be much easy to create the `service`.

Anyone knows how to establish a connection?

Comment: Follow the instruction here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate There is full code sample for python.

Comment: @JunYoung-Gwak You should post that as an answer. Those examples are of Web Flow authentication, though.

Comment: @AMS It is Stackoverflow policy not to write link-only answer. The link I commented pretty much answers the problem and there is nothing to add on top of it. Therefore, I should comment this, not answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had a some difficulty figuring out how to use the google calendar api with OAuth etc. I finally got everything working and along the way I wrote a very simple easy to use package. I posted it to github and it can be installed from pypi using "pip install gback". The documentation has instructions for google account settings also.

https://github.com/Schwarzschild/gback

Here is an example snippit for adding an appointment to a calendar.

```
from gback import GCalSession

# print the output will display the appiointment url.
# 'Marc' is the name of the calendar used.

session = GCalSession('~/gback.oauth')
des='Write a simpler way to use the google calendar api.'
print session['Marc'].add('Write Python code.', '20150430', des=des)
```

Enjoy, Marc

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a better Google Calendar API, I'd suggest [gcsa](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/Google-Calendar-Simple-API). It is the library I've developed (and still developing) for myself when had huge problems understanding and using official API.